# Link not working in second instance of page, if entering the page through that same link, the link sends one to the page with a long URL Query

Tags: url, hyperlink, href

I'm working with really long URLs or more specifically URL Queries and I've encountered a problem.

If I do a < a href..> with the URL that I've appended to the bottom of this post and click it it gives me the same page as I was on but with a long URL Query, since it's the same page it contains this same < a href..> with the same URL, now if I click that link again it does NOT send me to a new instance of that page, it does nothing, why would it do that? I want my links to work no matter what instance of the page it is.

So basically I have a page with a link that links to the same page but with a query, this link only works in the first instance of the page, not the second, if entering the page through that link.

I've only tested this in Firefox and Chromium.

I've put up an example of this here: http://173.45.231.202/hypnotic/link_problem.html , the URL in question is the following..

link_problem.html?polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|38.965754721680526|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|57.137905129116724|49.37333377604111|-85.51712263915974|54.54971467809152|-94.48287736084026|2.5881904510252065|-124.48287736084026|-2.5881904510252056|-115.51712263915974&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|38.965754721680526|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|57.137905129116724|-54.54971467809152|-94.48287736084026|-49.37333377604111|-85.51712263915974|2.5881904510252074|-115.51712263915974|-2.588190451025209|-124.48287736084026&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|120|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|10.352761804100828|-5.176380902050414|6.339028942455745e-16|5.176380902050414|-1.267805788491149e-15|5.176380902050414|-120|-5.176380902050414|-120&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|10.352761804100822|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|103.92304845413263|-51.96152422706631|-95.17638090205041|-51.96152422706631|-84.82361909794959|51.96152422706631|-84.82361909794959|51.96152422706631|-95.17638090205041&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|95.17638090205041|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|60.92727894874685|-4.482877360840267|-2.5881904510252056|4.482877360840268|2.5881904510252034|56.44440158790658|-87.41180954897479|47.47864686622604|-92.58819045102521&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|59.99999999999999|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|10.352761804100822|46.7851433250159|-30.000000000000007|57.137905129116724|-30.000000000000007|57.137905129116724|-90|46.7851433250159|-90&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|95.17638090205043|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|60.92727894874685|-47.47864686622604|-92.58819045102521|-56.44440158790658|-87.41180954897479|-4.482877360840266|2.5881904510252065|4.482877360840267|-2.588190451025205&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|59.99999999999999|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|10.352761804100822|-57.137905129116724|-30.000000000000007|-46.7851433250159|-30.000000000000007|-46.7851433250159|-90|-57.137905129116724|-90&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|10.352761804100826|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|103.92304845413263|-51.96152422706631|-35.17638090205042|-51.96152422706631|-24.823619097949592|51.96152422706631|-24.823619097949592|51.96152422706631|-35.17638090205042&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|38.96575472168054|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|57.137905129116724|54.54971467809152|-25.51712263915974|49.37333377604111|-34.48287736084027|-2.5881904510252047|-4.482877360840267|2.5881904510252056|4.482877360840267&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|59.99999999999999|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|10.35276180410083|46.78514332501591|29.999999999999986|57.13790512911673|29.999999999999986|57.137905129116724|-30.000000000000007|46.7851433250159|-30.000000000000007&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|38.96575472168054|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|57.137905129116724|-2.5881904510252083|4.4828773608402654|2.5881904510252074|-4.482877360840266|-49.37333377604111|-34.48287736084028|-54.54971467809152|-25.51712263915974&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|60.000000000000036|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|10.35276180410083|-57.13790512911672|30.00000000000003|-46.785143325015895|30.00000000000003|-46.7851433250159|-30.000000000000007|-57.137905129116724|-30.000000000000007&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|38.96575472168051|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|57.13790512911673|49.373333776041115|34.48287736084025|54.549714678091526|25.517122639159716|2.5881904510252065|-4.482877360840266|-2.5881904510252056|4.482877360840266&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|60|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|10.352761804100835|-5.176380902050407|60|5.176380902050421|60|5.176380902050414|-1.1493874523372613e-15|-5.176380902050414|6.339028942455745e-16&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|38.965754721680554|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|57.13790512911673|-54.54971467809152|25.517122639159762|-49.37333377604109|34.48287736084029|2.588190451025209|4.4828773608402654|-2.588190451025209|-4.4828773608402654&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|10.352761804100869|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|103.92304845413263|-51.961524227066306|24.823619097949614|-51.961524227066306|35.17638090205044|51.96152422706632|35.1763809020504|51.96152422706632|24.82361909794957&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|38.96575472168054|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|57.137905129116724|-2.5881904510252016|55.51712263915974|2.588190451025217|64.48287736084026|54.549714678091526|34.48287736084025|49.37333377604111|25.51712263915972&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|95.17638090205043|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|60.92727894874683|-4.482877360840252|117.41180954897479|4.482877360840283|122.5881904510252|56.44440158790658|32.58819045102519|47.47864686622605|27.41180954897478&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|38.965754721680504|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|57.137905129116724|-2.5881904510251963|64.48287736084026|2.588190451025211|55.51712263915973|-49.3733337760411|25.51712263915976|-54.54971467809151|34.4828773608403&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|95.1763809020504|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|60.927278948746846|-4.48287736084025|122.58819045102521|4.4828773608402805|117.41180954897479|-47.47864686622604|27.41180954897482|-56.44440158790657|32.588190451025234&polygon|0|1|#FFFFFF|60|350|1|1|1|#000000|1.5|350|10.352761804100837|-5.176380902050399|120|5.176380902050429|120|5.176380902050421|60|-5.176380902050407|60&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|350|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|230|40|&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|401.9615242270663|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|260|40|&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|298.0384757729337|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|260|40|&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|401.9615242270663|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|320|40|&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|298.0384757729337|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|320|40|&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|350|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|350|40|&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|401.9615242270663|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|380|40|&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|298.0384757729337|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|380|40|&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|350|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|410|40|&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|350|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|470|40|&circle|0|1|#FFFFFF|40|350|1|1|1|#000000|2.5|290|40|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|353.5|0|0.5|0.5|null|1||230.35|37|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|405.4615242270663|0|0.5|0.5|null|1|%E2%9A%8A%7C260.35|37|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|301.5384757729337|0|0.5|0.5|null|1|%E2%9A%8B%7C260.35|37|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|405.4615242270663|0|0.5|0.5|null|1|%E2%98%B1%7C320.35|37|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|301.5384757729337|0|0.5|0.5|null|1|%E2%98%B3%7C320.35|37|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|353.5|0|0.5|0.5|null|1|%E2%98%B2%7C350.35|37|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|405.4615242270663|0|0.5|0.5|null|1|%E2%98%B6%7C380.35|37|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|301.5384757729337|0|0.5|0.5|null|1|%E2%98%B4%7C380.35|37|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|353.5|0|0.5|0.5|null|1|%E2%98%B5%7C410.35|37|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|353.5|0|0.5|0.5|null|1|%E2%98%B7%7C470.35|37|&text|0|1|rgb(0,0,0)|DejaVu%20Sans|20|100|40|353.5|0|0.5|0.5|null|1|%E2%98%B0%7C290.35|37|

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a POST request instead! GET request sizes are limited by browsers, web servers and who knows what else, from anything between about 256 characters to 4000. So generally, it is unreliable to send massive amounts of data through an ordinary GET. Submit that using POST, through a HTML form, and you should not face any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum supported URL length (of a GET) in IE is 2048 characters. Generally speaking you want to avoid anything over about 500 bytes since certain browser and server implementations won't support it.

If youn need larger sets use a POST from either a form action or an AJAX request that processes the return value from the server.